# Stack implementation using LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I came across this solution for stack implementation using Linked List on Leetcode and I understood almost all the logic behind it except the min part. Can anyone please explain how the code is keep tracking of the minimum element after the first minimum element is popped?

Code

```
class MinStack {
    private Node head;
        
    public void push(int x) {
        if (head == null) 
            head = new Node(x, x, null);
        else 
            head = new Node(x, Math.min(x, head.min), head);
    }
    
    public void pop() {
        head = head.next;
    }
    
    public int top() {
        return head.val;
    }
    
    public int getMin() {
        return head.min;
    }
        
    private class Node {
        int val;
        int min;
        Node next;
            
        private Node(int val, int min, Node next) {
            this.val = val;
            this.min = min;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the implementation, but it does not seem to work ([Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/XqXOBd)).

Comment: @Turing85 the test code you use starts by pushing `0` and increments from there, so the minimum will always be `0`.

Comment: @TimMoore I know. But I would normally expect hat the data structure organizes the values internally (like a min heap). But thenn again: Maybe i misunderstand the implementation. Without a clear problem statement, it is hard to know what the exact requirements for the data structure are.

Comment: It isn't ordering by minimum element, it's just tracking what the minimum is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push a new node to the head of the stack, the new minimum will either be the new node, or the previous minimum, which is stored in the previous head. When you pop the head, it reverts back to the previous minimum, stored in the previous head. Because `getMin()` always looks at the current head, this gives the correct result.

Try stepping through some examples:

1. Start with an empty stack
2. push 5 -> stack with one node with `val = 5`, `min = 5`, `next = null`

   (I'll use abbreviated notation `(val, min, next)` like `(5, 5, null)` from now on)
3. push 10 -> stack with two nodes `(10, 5, (5, 5, null))`
4. push 1 -> `(1, 1, (10, 5, (5, 5, null)))`
5. pop -> back to `(10, 5, (5, 5, null))`
6. pop -> back to `(5, 5, null)`

Comment: ```When you pop the head, it reverts back to the previous minimum, stored in the previous head.``` This line is golden, thank you so much. I even saw this when I debugged the code in my IDE but i didn't paid much attention at that time cz somehow I was more focused that something magical is happening internally which i was really curious to know about . But now when you mentioned it , it immediately clicked and it all makes sense now. Thank you so much again!!